# JTA Transaction: What happens if an exception happens but rollback is not called on the transaction?

Tags: java, mysql, transactions, jta

We have some third party code wherein they do the following

1. List item

   Create a User Transaction e.g.

   ```
    txn = (UserTransaction)ctx.lookup( "UserTransaction" );
    txn.begin(  );
   ```
2. Do some work persisting to the database (via JPA) to a MySQL database
3. `txn.commit()`

They have Exception blocks but NONE of them call `txn.rollback`.
Good coding practice says they NEED to call rollback if an exception occurs but my question is
If the txn is not committed, and an exception occurs what is the negative effect of them NOT calling rollback?

Answer (score 4):

The transaction stays active, until you either `commit()` or `rollback()` it. It will continue to hold locks and you may end up blocking your application (database, actually).

Answer (score 1):

IMO the JTA transaction should eventually timeout (based on the set or default transactionTimeout) and should automatically rollback.